# When to explicitly specify type arguments in generic C# method calls?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class that offers common methods for predicates of concrete types (I use `PredicateBuilder` extention methods for that)

```
public class GenericPredicate<TItem>
{
    protected GenericPredicate(Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> predicate)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
    }

    protected GenericPredicate()
    {
    }

    public Expression<Func<TItem, bool>> Predicate { get; protected set; }

    //Combines two predicates
    public TPred And<TPred>(TPred second) where TPred : GenericPredicate<TItem>, new()
    {
        return new TPred { Predicate = Predicate.And(second.Predicate) };
    }

    //Negates the predicate
    public TPred Not<TPred>() where TPred : GenericPredicate<TItem>, new()
    {
        return new TPred { Predicate = Predicate.Not() };
    }
}
```

And concrete predicates:

```
public class PersonPredicate : GenericPredicate<Person>
{
    protected PersonPredicate(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate)
        : base(predicate)
    {
    }

    public PersonPredicate()
    {
    }

    public static PersonPredicate IsAdult()
    {
        return new PersonPredicate(p => p.Age >= 18);
    }

    public static PersonPredicate IsFemale()
    {
        return new PersonPredicate(p => Equals(p.Gender, Gender.Female));
    }
}
```

In the factory where I instantiate the concrete predicates I get the error

> The type arguments for method Not cannot be inferred from the usage

when calling the generic `Not()`

```
PersonPredicate isFemale = PersonPredicate.IsFemale();
PersonPredicate isAdult = PersonPredicate.IsAdult();
PersonPredicate femaleAndAdult = isFemale.And(isAdult);
PersonPredicate notFemale = isFemale.Not(); //Error as described
PersonPredicate notFemaleWorkaround = isFemale.Not<PersonPredicate>();  // Works as suggested by compiler
```

So, the compiler doesn't know what `TItem` is. What makes me confused is that the generic `And()` method works without specifying the type arguments explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, type inference for generic type parameters works based on the *arguments* you pass to the method.

So `And()` works, because you're passing in an `isAdult`. The compiler infers that `TPred` is `PersonPredict` as that's the type of `isAdult` and there are no other constraints.

For `Not()`, you're not passing in any arguments, so the compiler has no information about what you want `TPred` to be. That's what it can't infer - not `TItem`.

If you really wanted this to work, you could declare `GenericPredicate` with *two* type parameters, one of which is expected to be the subclass itself

```
public class GenericPredicate<TPred, TItem>
    where TPred : GenericPredicate<TPred, TItem>, new()
```

and:

```
public class PersonPredicate : GenericPredicate<PersonPredicate, Person>
```

You might want to have `GenericPredicate<TPred,TItem>` as a subclass of `GenericPredicate<TItem>`, so that other code could still *accept* just a `GenericPredicate<TItem>`. However, at this point it's all pretty convoluted - you may well better off just specifying the type argument.

Comment: I'm wondering why I didn't earned a "You've been skeeted" badge !?

Comment: Thanks Jon for the subclass workaround. I'll discuss that with my team

Answer (score 1):

In both your examples, the compiler tries to determine the type of predicate `TPred` that should be used to resolve the function.

In this example:

```
isFemale.And(isAdult);
```

the compiler sees that a `PersonPredicate` called `isAdult` has been passed in to the function. Thus, it can determine that in the function call, `TPred` is actually `PersonPredicate`.

In the other example,

```
isFemale.Not();
```

the compiler has no hints to understand what fits into `TPred`. Hence it needs specific instructions to resolve the conflict.

```
isFemale.Not<PersonPredicate>();
```

Now the compiler can resolve the call correctly.

---

Finally, you may think that because you are assigning the result of the function call to a `PersonPredicate`, the compiler should have picked this up. Unfortunately, function target resolution does not consider the assigned value. This is because there are other factors which come into play when you assign values using `=`. There may be implicit type casts defined, the operator may have been overloaded, or there may be an implicit constructor. So there is no guarantee that the assignee will be the same type as the actual value.

Comment: Thanks, now that makes sense. I googled for such a clear and simple explanation